# Has there been a change to the way that mysql-python-connector works when using executemany to insert a large list of tuples into a database table?

Tags: python, mysql, conda, mysql-connector-python

I'm executing the following code to insert a list of tuples into a `mysql` database using the `mysql-connector-python` package.

```
import mysql.connector
import random
from time import time

# Create a list of tuples for the database
datalist = [(i, random.random()) for i in range(0, 1000000)]

# Dump the derived data to the MySQL database
config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database':'testdatabase',
}

t1 = time()

con_MySQL = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
cur_MySQL = con_MySQL.cursor()

sql_insert = """
INSERT INTO test (id, data) VALUES (%s, %s)
"""

cur_MySQL.executemany(sql_insert, datalist)
cur_MySQL.close()
con_MySQL.close()

t2 = time()

print(f'Elapsed time is {t2 - t1} seconds.')
```

This previously took only a short time of about 10 seconds when using a `conda` environment with the following packages:

```
mysql                     5.7.24               hbb652a2_0  
mysql-common              8.0.25               ha770c72_2    conda-forge
mysql-connector-python    8.0.25           py39h664ec74_0    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.25               hfa10184_2    conda-forge
```

I then changed to using `mamba` as my package manager and now execute the script in an environment with the following packages:

```
mysql                     8.0.32               h27aab58_0    conda-forge
mysql-client              8.0.32               hb89bdb7_0    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.32               ha901b37_0    conda-forge
mysql-connector-python    8.0.31          py310h3a1307d_2    conda-forge
mysql-devel               8.0.32               ha901b37_0    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.32               hd7da12d_0    conda-forge
mysql-server              8.0.32               h02d985f_0    conda-forge
```

The script runs successfully again but it takes much longer with an execution time of about 550 seconds. I've also noticed that previously all the rows seemed to have been inserted in one go in the old environment. In the new environment the rows seem to be inserted individually into the database table which leads to the slow execution time. Does anyone have any experience on what may be causing this issue or if the connector has changed in operation?

Comment: What are the values of MySQL `max_packet_size` in the two tests. `executemany()` breaks the list into batches to fit this limit.

Comment: I've set the `max_allowed_packet` system variable to 1073741824 on the server. Normally if this is too low then an exception is thrown in Python.

Comment: Then I can't think of a good reason why it's doing it as one query per row. executemany is supposed to batch it up. It's open code and very easy to read, I suggest you check the source.

Comment: See https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/3fe87a163de1c1dfcf1de60bbabecc30394c3ef6/lib/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py#L452

Comment: This was a performance regression introduced by a bug fix. It was fixed in 8.0.33. Please upgrade Connector/Python. Here’s the release note: “Executing executemany() with insert statements that used 'on duplicate key update' demonstrated poor performance; improved speed by fixing the associated regular expressions that match insert statements. (Bug #99575, Bug #31355895)”

Comment: Upgrading `mysql-connector-python` to version 8.0.33 has indeed fixed the issue.